# Can I adjust hard drive space without re-installing Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I set up a partition of about 200gb and installed ubuntu from a usb stick. When I run "free -g" from the command line I only see 5 gb of total space. During the installation I clicked install along side windows but was never asked about partition space, which I thought was weird. Do I have to re-install ubuntu to fix this? If this is true, I did try rebooting with the usb stick in, but it was not recognized during the boot process.

Comment: boot ubuntu live disk,click on try ubuntu option , open gparted partition editor from Dash,then upload it's screenshot to imgur.com and post the link here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,you can adjust the hard-drive space without reinstalling Ubuntu using Ubuntu live disk and Gparted partition Editor.

Comment: It seems as though I was maybe misinterpreting the results of the free  command to be available hd space. (Fortunately?) I can't verify your solution.

Comment: Upload  gparted screenshot.